# Calculating gradient with prewitt operator

Tags: computer-vision, gradient

I am new and trying to learn about it.

I searched all kinds of links on Google but there was something about
I would be happy if you could tell me how to perform calculations on gradient But by calculating on prewitt operator.

for example:
you have image 5X5  ->  I(x,y) = |4-i-j|;
                                           i,j = 0..4;

How i to calculate with prewitt operator (Gx and Gy) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient calculations on images are performed using a mathematical operation called [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). The formula for convolution of two matrices `f` and `g` is given below.

[image]

In pseudocode, the algorithm would be:

```
let f be the prewitt (convolution) operator
let g be the image
let h be the convolution result

for x from 1 to height of h
    for y from 1 to width of h
       h[x,y] = 0;
       for n1 from top to bottom of f
           for n2 from left to right of f
               h[x,y] += f[n1,n2]*g[x-n1,y-n2]
```

Some languages/libraries implement convolution for you.

- The MATLAB language has the built-in [`conv2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html)
- The Python library numpy as the function [`numpy.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

Answer (score 0):

The popular `scipy` package for python has a built-in function `prewitt` for calculating exactly what you describe:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.prewitt.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.prewitt